# React JS - setState cannot be called on a component not yet mounted

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios

I have my Application in React JS. I am fetching data from an API at http://localhost:8080/api/suppliers/supplier/list:

Here is the data that I am getting from the REST API in the Google Chrome console:

```
0:{
    id: 4
    supplierFirstname: "Tom"
    supplierLastName: "ABC"
    supplierTitle: "TomTheSupplier"
    accountNumber: 1122234444
    address: "111 ADrive, 1234 ST."
    companyName: "TheTom Company & Associates"
    email: "tomtomjayjay@email.com"
    hourlyRate: 29
    phoneNumber: 123456789
    otherPhoneNumber: 1023456789
    paymentTerms: "Credit"
    notes: "Some Supplier"
    createdAt: null
    typeOfGoods: "Supplies"
    website: "www.abc_123.com"
    products: [{…}]
    components: 
        [
            0: {id: 5, name: "AComponent", unit: null, quantity: 0, componentCost: 0, …}
        ]
    
}
```

Here is my React code:

```
class SupplierData extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      supplier: [
        {
          id: 0,
          supplierTitle: "Supplier Title",
          supplierFirstName: "First Name",
          supplierLastName: "Last Name",
          companyName: "Company Name",
          phoneNumber: "Phone Number",
          otherPhoneNumber: "Phone Number (Other)",
          accountNumber: "Account Number",
          email: "Email",
          address: "Address",
          website: "Website",
          hourlyRate: "Hourly Rate",
          typeOfGoods: "Type Of Goods",
          paymentTerms: "Payment Terms",
          createdAt: "Created At",
          notes: "Notes",
          products: "Products",
          components: "Components",
        },
      ],
      errorMessage: [],
    };
    
  }

  listAllSuppliers = async () => {
    return await axios
      .get(`http://localhost:8080/api/suppliers/supplier/list`)
      .then((response) => {
        let apiResults = response.data;
        console.log(apiResults);
        this.setState({ supplier: apiResults });    <--- The error happens here.
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        this.setState({ errorMessage: this.state.errorMessage.push(error) });
      });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.ListAllSuppliers();
  }
}

export default SupplierData;
```

The problem that I am facing is in the React State. I am getting the following error:

```
Warning: Can't call setState on a component that is not yet mounted. This is a no-op, but it might 
         indicate a bug in your application. Instead, assign to `this.state` directly or define a `state = 
         {};` class property with the desired state in the SupplierData component.
```

**Question 1:**  **(Very Important)**
I want to set the state.

What is a possible fix the above error?

**Question 2:**
Is this the right way to call the above class in the following file.
I have the following code:

```
    import SupplierData from './..';



    export const A = (props) =>{
    const {id, supplierTitle, supplierFirstName, supplierLastName, 
           companyName, phoneNumber, otherPhoneNumber, accountNumber, email, 
           address, website, hourlyRate, typeOfGoods, paymentTerms, 
           createdAt, notes, products, components, status } = props;


       let mySupplier = new SupplierData();
       let listData = mySupplier.listAllSuppliers();


       return(
        <tr>
            <td>
                <Card.Link as={Link} to={Routes.Suppliers.path} className="fw-normal">
                   {SupplierData.map((t, id) => <tr key={id}> {t.fetchedData} </tr>)}  <--- Here is where the error is
                </Card.Link>
            </td>
         </tr>
       );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixing Question 2 is the way to fix Question 1, and so I'll answer Question 2:

No, that is absolutely not the right way to call a React component.

`SupplierData` is a React component, and since you already have the `componentDidMount()` lifecycle method calling `listAllSuppliers()`, all you need to do is mount a `SupplierData` component:

```
import SupplierData from "./..";

export const A = (props) => {
  return (
    <tr>
      <td>
        <Card.Link as={Link} to={Routes.Suppliers.path} className="fw-normal">
          <SupplierData />
        </Card.Link>
      </td>
    </tr>
  );
};
```

### Edit based on comments

A very simple reformulation of what you *might* want to achieve here is as follows.

Since your API result example plainly describes an object containing objects, and your code seems to assume an array, I couldn't tell what's actually correct. For that reason the rendering code just dumps the loaded data.

Also, error handling is missing.

```
const SupplierData = () => {
  const [supplier, setSupplier] = React.useState(null);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(`http://localhost:8080/api/suppliers/supplier/list`)
      .then((response) => setSupplier(response.data))
      .catch(alert);
  }, []);
  if (supplier === null) return <>Loading...</>;
  // TODO: implement better rendering code
  return <>{JSON.stringify(supplier)}</>;
};

export const A = (props) => {
  return (
    <>
      Hello, world!
      <SupplierData />
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: I have added specifically where the error is to my question. Please check and let me know your suggestion. Appreciate your time.

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like you're misunderstanding how React components and their local state work. You would need to map that data in the component that has the state - add a render method to SupplierData...